# What is the most frequent way to send an HTTP request in the industry at the moment (AJAX, Fetch API, Async/Await)?

Tags: javascript

I know that AJAX used to be more prevalent in the past when it came to creating HTTP requests and i'm curious on what the industry standard is now?

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges. AJAX is just about sending requests asynchronously with JS. The Fetch API is an abstraction on top of the lower level XMLHttpRequest API. Async/Await is just syntax sugar to have your code looks synchronous.

Comment: Fetch returns a Promise that you can use with async/await. This is mainly to prevent callback hell.

Comment: @sp00m You can't use `await` in Internet Explorer - or with `XMLHttpRequest`, unfortunately

Comment: @Dai Yeah fair enough, I've over simplified a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

- Generally speaking, "AJAX" does not refer to any specific API or technology for script-initiated HTTP requests.
- AJAX has been performed using `XMLHttpRequest` for most of the past 15 years.
- As of 2019, `fetch` effectively replaces `XMLHttpRequest` because it exposes a JavaScript native `Promise<T>` asynchronous API which can be used with `await`.

  - However, `fetch` does not support reporting progress information (especially for client-side uploads) whereas `XMLHttpRequest` does, so `XMLHttpRequest` is still relevant in many applications for this reason.
- However, you can still use `Promise<T>` as a wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest` - and this is how the `fetch` polyfills for Internet Explorer works.